# Having trouble with our displayIng function in our school project

Tags: javascript

So we are using CocktailDB for our API key in the bootcamp that i am in and its working but on the page that displays our Ingredients and Directions on how to make the cocktail it wont display. Here is our function in JavaScript, any answers or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

```
function displayIng(id){
    ingPg.style.display = "block";
    listPg.style.display = "none";

    searchIng(id);
    
    //search for ingredients and directions with id
    var ingredients = [resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient1, resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient2, resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient3, resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient4, resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient5,
    resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient6, resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient7, resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient8, resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient9, resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient10, 
    resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient11, resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient12, resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient13, resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient14, resultsIng.drinks[0].strIngredient15];
    
     console.log(ingredients);

    var dir = resultsIng.drinks[0].strInstructions; 
    var directions = dir.split(".");

    for(var i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++){
        var list = document.createElement("li");
        list.textContent = ingredients[i];
        loi.appendChild(list);
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < directions.length; i++){
        var list = document.createElement("li");
        list.textContent = directions[i];
        dir.appendChild(list);
    }

    enjoyBtn.onclick = function(event){
        displayMusic();
    };
}
```

Comment: Try  to show a more finished example. Because we don't know what `resultsIng` is. Maybe you got an error from that array.

Comment: What does `searchIng(id)` do? I suspect it's asynchronous, and you're not waiting for it to finish.

Comment: See [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)